# Android image change image dimensions according to device screen size

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

I have an `imageView` whos width is `"match_parent"` (with some margins at each end).

Since different devices have different widths, the image is not filling the imageView but is leaving some gap at each end depending on which device am I viewing it on.

I have tried `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` but this stretches the image to fill the width which distorts the content badly.

what is the correct way? should I give android multiple copies of the image with different dimensions (like the multiple drawable folders for different pixel densities) ?

## update

tried scaleType to "fitXY" but this is still stretching the image not keeping aspect ratio.

this is my xml:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/inner_map"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header" />
```

I have inserted multiple copies with different resolutions of this image into the different drawable folders if this is of any importance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

Comment: this is still stretching the image.

Comment: try center crop

Comment: no, fitcenter with viewbound did not work but centercrop worked without view viewBounds

Comment: well i was pretty much in the dark as i had no clue how big or small your image was so was best guessing based on most likely scenarios :D

Comment: great, accept the answer, edited to the working one... next time do post the image dimensions :D